# Find polynomial with rational coefficients roots are $\sin^2\frac{\pi}{4m},\sin^2\frac{3\pi}{4m},\sin^2\frac{5\pi}{4m},...,\sin^2\frac{(2m-1)\pi}{4m}$

Tags: number-theory

I am stuck on this problem. Find polynomials with rational coefficients whose roots are $$\sin^2\frac{\pi}{4m},\;\sin^2\frac{3\pi}{4m},\;\sin^2\frac{5\pi}{4m},...,\;\sin^2\frac{(2m-1)\pi}{4m}.$$

I know \begin{align*}\cos(2m\alpha)=(1-\sin^2\alpha)^m&-\binom{2m}{2}  (1-\sin^2\alpha)^{m-1}(\sin^2\alpha)\\ & +\binom{2m}{4}(1-\sin^2\alpha)^{m-2}(\sin^4\alpha)-\cdots \end{align*}

and we use that to get the roots however im having trouble getting there.

Comment: The title uses polynomial, the body has it plural.  Do you expect one polynomial for each term in the first list, or one polynomial that covers all of them?  Maybe it's "just a typo" but you should review the post and get it right.  These are very different questions.  Then, of course, what have you tried?  You have shown one formula that might be useful, but no indication of why or how you will use it.

Comment: the title is also plural, just didnt have enough characters

Comment: For all angles $\alpha$ we have $$\sin^2\alpha=\frac12(1-\cos2\alpha).$$ Do you know the polynomial that has $\cos(\pi/2m)$, $\cos(3\pi/2m)$, $\ldots$, $\cos((2m-1)\pi/2m)$ as its zeros?

Comment: [Chebyshev polynomials](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chebyshev_polynomials) and some linear substitutions will get you there.